# What happens to the velocity if you decrease the radius in uniform circular motion?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, centripetal-force

**PROBLEM**
Suppose we have a frictionless table and we have a mass attached to a string rotating in a circular motion. If we decrease the radius by pulling string downwards (from a hole in the table), what will be the effect on the speed of the mass?
[image: Dig I made]
I came up with two solutions for this-

1. $$T = \frac{mv^2}{r}$$
   Acc to this solution $v^2$ is directly proportional to $rT$. So if the radius decreases, so should the speed.
2. Other approach is since we pull the string down slowly then the Torque at the center point will be zero and L(angular momentum) will be conserved. So we can conveniently write-
   $$L_1 = L_2 (L_1\;for\;initial)$$
   $$mv_1r_1 = mv_2r_2$$
   $$v_2 = \frac{v_1r_1}{r_2}$$
   As r<sub>2</sub> is less so v<sub>2</sub> should increase.
   Please tell me which one is correct and WHY?

Comment: I vote for 2. There is a  centrial force to reduce the radius, therefore the centripetal force is not constant. But since the extra force is acting in central direction, the torque is zero, leads to a constant angular momentum.

Comment: @ytlu I don't think that's right, the centripetal force is horizontal over here whereas string will be pulled down by a vertical force. The centripetal force will be eventually constant when we have reduced the radius.

Comment: It is transfered horizotal by the string. Yes. it will become constant, when the increasement in velocity will balance the larger centripetal force, another point of view,  maintain a constant angular momentum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation in option 1, $T = \frac{mv^2}{r}$, can't be used to state that the velocity on a circle with a smaller radius is smaller than that on a circle with a bigger $r$. In the way you envision. Why not? You write:

"So if the radius decreases, so should the speed",

which you infer from $rT = mv^2$ (which follows from $T = \frac{mv^2}{r}$). If you lower $r$ though (by making the string shorter) then you exert a force on the mass which makes its kinetic energy increase. While the last formula holds for two separate circular orbits, it can't be used to say that because $r$ gets lower, so must $v$. By lowering $r$, $T$ gets bigger and so does $v$. The relation $rT = mv^2$ will of course hold for all circular orbits.

Option two is not right either. The tension force, $\vec{T}$, acting on the mass gives rise to a non-zero torque. So momentum is not conserved. Just as momentum is not conserved for a mass that is accelerated in a gravitational force field. The kinetic energy of the mass increases and so does its momentum (of course, the total momentum of the mass that gives rise to the gravitational force and the accelerated mass has to be conserved).

And now for real. The torque $\vec{\tau}=\vec{T}\times\vec{r}$, the exterior product of $\vec{T}$ and $\vec{r}$. It points out of the table and perpendicular to it. If zero torque is applied to a circular moving mass then the angular momentum of the mass stays constant. The force only does work to increase the velocity of the mass, but the angular momentum is conserved. Just as applying zero force on a linearly moving mass conserves linear momentum.

I should get very lucky now!!!

Comment: I got your first point, I was also thinking that $T$ will compensate the loss by $r$, but for your second point you say Torque is not zero at the center point, how? $τ = r * F$, all are vectors, idk how to add the symbol. So $τ$ should be zero, force is towards the center ( Tension Force )

Comment: Its a string attached to that mass and the circle is its path, I am defining the torque on the center of the circle and taking L at that point only.

Comment: @VyomYadav  You are right in saying that the torque is zero, upon closer examination. Because of the fact that $\vec{\tau}=\vec{T}x\vec{r}$. And zero torque leads indeed to the conservation of angular momentum. I think I was misled by the fact that the force does work which makes the velocity increase.

Comment: No problem brother, thanks for helping out.

Comment: @VyomYadav All right then!

Comment: @VyomYadav One more thing. I don't know if you want to ask more questions, but if you do then you can find a way to make mathematical expressions on this site: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference    Or here:   https://www.mathjax.org

Answer (score 1):

Conservation of angular momentum dictates that it will speed up as the area swept out per unit time is a constant.

as for your first solution i have no idea where u got that the velocity square is directly proportional to rT as in this case r is a variable not a constant

Comment: I just added a picture also, the first equation I got was from the newtons 2nd law in standstill condition.

Comment: i get where u got the equation from. centripetal force... however  T=mv^2/r   doesnt mean that v^2 is proportional to r. proportionality occurs when something is a constant. take v=ir if r is constant then v is propprtional to i. however r is a variable that you change... so it cannot itself be a proportionality constant

Comment: If the product of two variables (x ⋅ y) is equal to a constant (k = x ⋅ y), then the two are said to be inversely proportional to each other with the proportionality constant k. Here neither x is const nor y. In my equation, neither $r$ is const nor is $v^2$. Const of proportionality here is $m$

Comment: What I think that $T$ will also vary, I think that it will increase and compensate for the decrease of $r$. I just need proof for it.